# Why does Facebook uses the img tag with PHP link

Tags: php, facebook

I was debugging a few things, and at that time I found the following image tag:

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="https://pixel.facebook.com/ajax/ego_height.php?sid=ads&amp;fbid=34324234&amp;height=0&amp;asyncSignal=4815&amp;__user=23232323&amp;__a=1&amp;fb_dtsg=AQCVSss">
```

Why does Facebook use this `img` tag for calling a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) file?

Comment: The php file generates an image.

Comment: It's programmers community , every one have rights to as question related programs. If you'r not interested answer the question then please don't spoil my question.

Comment: @Musa yes , but its only 1X1 Pixel.

Comment: @SSK There's nothing to do here.  To know why they generate a 1x1 pixel images is something only they would know.

Comment: It could be anything. Sometimes it's a hack to run a script on the server side without using javascript. The browser sends a request expecting an image, the server runs the php script, generates that useless image, and nobody knows what happened on the other side.

Comment: @Daedalus I asked any idea not exact answer or not 100% sure.

Comment: @Daedalus That is called as debugging & if we got to know we can also use in our programs

Comment: @SSK I know what debugging is.. this isn't it.  You can't figure out how exactly a website works unless you have access to the server.. either that, or they directly tell you..  One could figure out if a website used joomla by inspecting the html, but to know or even guess why an image is referencing a php page could be anything.

Comment: @Daedalus That's seriously great. what i am trying to guess it ! If we can guess it ! we will try to execute our php code in our web app system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually a pretty common practice.

Due security reasons, you're not able to do an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request to a third-party domain. And you really have no choice but sending data by loading an image OR loading JavaScript code which is actually server-side code. Or you can do both (as [Google Analytics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics) works, they just load JavaScript which handles all events on the page and register them by loading a pixel image with analytics parameters passed).

Comment: Yeah , right ! do u have any example of code , to perform this task ?

Comment: I personally haven't had a chance to develop something like this but i think it's pretty straightforward. I've analyzed how GA tracking works and it's something like this: Page accumulates data in _gaq array. and then (normally on page load) GA script is loaded. It'll call the image via <img> tag or just creating an image object. Then ga will replace _gaq with dynamic object and all further events will be registered separately as new image requests.

Answer (score 0):

Because this image is dynamically generated or loaded by the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) script. The src can be any [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), not only image files.

Comment: Yes but it's shows 1X1 pix image , i don't think so they are using it for image ..

Comment: then it must be used for tracking, just like google analytics