# Why the services like 'ping' always return 'image'?

Tags: mime-types, ping, web-analytics

There are lots of web services (mostly real-time & AJAX for analysis) like [heart-beat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeat_%28computing%29) or [clickstream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickstream) out there.

I found that they basically all return as `image/png` or `image/gif` instead of `text/html` or some other MIME types.

Are image MIME types more effective or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Facebook uses the img tag with PHP link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859803/why-does-facebook-uses-the-img-tag-with-php-link)

Answer (score 0):

The heartbeat is implemented via an image tag:

```
  <img src="heartbeat.php"/>
```

to circumvent the [same-origin-policy](/questions/tagged/same-origin-policy).